# Unity get swipe angle

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, touch

I handle two CONTACT A , pressing and releasing the screen , how do I get the rotation angle ? To run the ball like this wonderful game .

```
void Start () {
    guiText.text = "Touch the screen.";
    AddForce ();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    touch = Input.GetTouch (0);
    TouchPhase phase = touch.phase;
    switch(phase)
    {
    case TouchPhase.Began:
        guiText.text =("New touch detected at position " + touch.position);
        a_pos = touch.position;
        break;
    case TouchPhase.Ended:
        guiText.text =("Has cansel by " + touch.position);
        b_pos = touch.position;
        Calculate();
        AddForce ();
        break;      

        }
    }
```

[Instruction](http://mgc-friends.com/1.jpg)

[Wonderful game](http://appshopper.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/paper-toss-hd-pub.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a vector from the start of the swipe the end of the swipe:

```
 Vector2 swipe = b_pos - a_pos;
```

If you want to find the angle between that vector and horizontal axes you can calculate:

```
float angle = Vector2.Angle(Vector.right, swipe);
```

But if you are going to use the angle for `AddForce`, you can convert `a_pos` and `b_pos` from screen coordinates to world coordinates and use those points to make the vector for `AddForce`:

```
Vector3 forceDirection = camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(b_pos) - camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(a_pos)
```

Comment: Big thanks, but i need to do something else, look here i'm makeed really good scheme of Ball AdForce logic :)
[SCHEME](http://mgc-friends.com/how_to.png)